# I'm getting an index error out of range in my code

Tags: python, indexing

**code**

To sort row sorted arrays
a is of size m and b is of size n

```
t=int(input())
for i in range(0,t):
    n,m,k=map(int,input().split())
    a=list(map(int,input().split()))
    b=list(map(int,input().split()))
j=0
x=0
y=0
c=[]
while x!=m and y!=n:
    if a[x]<b[y]:
        c.append(a[x])
        x+=1
        #j+=1
    elif a[x]==b[y]:
        c.append(a[x])
        x+=1
        y+=1
        #j+=1
    else:
        c.append(b[y])
        y+=1
while x<m:
        c.append(a[x])
        x+=1
while y<n:
        c.append(b[y])
        y+=1
```

**Error:**

> c.append(b[y]) IndexError: list index out of range

this is the error I'm getting and why it so.
I haven't even defined the size of array c so why is it a problem

Comment: I don't get an error, but wonder If x[x]==b[y], why does both x and y get incremented (i.e. x+=1, and y+=1).  Seems you could remove this conditional and change conditional above it from a[x] < a[y] to a[x] <= a[y].

Comment: Looks like `b` array is NOT size `n`, but if you don't show us the code that tells the size of `b`, we can't review it. In addition, from your identination, it is not clear what's in each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! Hope this helps

> c.append(b[y]) IndexError: list index out of range

In python, all the items in list can be using their index,.i.e. position in the list.

In the code `c.append(b[y])`, there are two parts

1. `b[y]` implies, => from the list `b` get the item at index `y`.

Now say you have a list `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. As you can see this list has only 5 elements. Now if I ask python to get me an element at index 6 or 7 or 10, how to get? So, to notify the user that you this *IndexError* exception is raised.

2. appending fetched item to list c. Before this could happen, above error occurred, so this part never happened.

One way to ensure you have that IndexError does not occur is have a if condition like below

```
if y < len(b):
    c.append(b[y])
```

**Note**: `list` is more like a linked-list than array. So you dont need to specify the length